# Is it possible to use hashcat or john the ripper on a .drmz file?

Tags: hash, pdf, hashcat, john-the-ripper

I have n `.drmz` files which I can read with Javelin PDF Reader. Obviously to access the content I need a password, which I have, the same for each file.

In case I don't have the password is there a way to find it via John The Ripper or HashCat? If yes how I can calculate the hash?

On [this](https://hashcat.net/wiki/doku.php?id=example_hashes) example guide `.drmz` is not listed so I suppose is not possible, but probably I'm missing something. Right?

- n stands for number of files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. When encryption schemes are not supported by {HashCat, JTR}, people typically write a tool that identifies the scheme in use by the format and extracts the raw key, which can then be attacked.<sup>[1]</sup> Unfortunately no such tool exists for DRMZ files. You may be able to write one yourself, but you'd have to reverse engineer the DRMZ format to some degree first.

[1]: For example [pdf2john](https://github.com/openwall/john/blob/bleeding-jumbo/run/pdf2john.pl)

Comment: It is possible to convert to .pdf permanently a .drmz file for which the password instead is already known?